# Recursively delete a list of values from object

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I have a list of ids as

```
ids = [6,9]
```

and a object which is an array of objects as

```
data = {
    "child": [{
            "fruit": "apple",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "fruit": "mango",
            "id": 2,
            "child": [{
                "name": "js",
                "id": 4
            }, {
                "name": "jsk",
                "id": 6
            }]
        },
        {
            "fruit": "banana",
            "id": 9
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to iterate over data to find any object with id present in list of ids.Here I have to delete

```
{"name":"jsk", "id": 6}
```

and

```
{"fruit":"banana","id":9}
```

To achieve this I have written following code

```
deleteObj = (data, ids) => {
  data.child.forEach((key, index) => {
    if(key && ids.indexOf(child.id) > -1){
      console.log("inside match before", key);
      key.splice(index, 1);
      console.log("inside match after: ", key);
    }
    if(key.child) {
      deleteObj(key, ids);
    }
  })
};
```

But in this function after getting first match it simply return.Deliting only first matched id.
Pring only `inside match after:9`
Not able to find any error

Comment: what is `findBookmarkDeletedIds`

Comment: You have two issues inside of deleteObj. In the first if statement, you check `child.id`, but you should be checking `key.id`. Second, your splice call should be invoked on `data.child` instead of `key`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple `while` loop and iterate from the end, because splicing deletes the actual index and with moving on, you get an unprocessed item.

```js
function deleteItems(array, ids) {
    var i = array.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (ids.indexOf(array[i].id) !== -1) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
            continue;
        }
        array[i].child && deleteItems(array[i].child, ids);
    }
}

var ids = [6, 9],
    data = { child: [{ fruit: "apple", id: 1 }, { fruit: "mango", id: 2, child: [{ name: "js", id: 4 }, { name: "jsk", id: 6 }] }, { fruit: "banana", id: 9 }] };

deleteItems([data], ids)
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you loop and remove element form original array you get a problem because the array is being re-indexed and you skip some elements, so instead you can loop in reverse.

```js
var data = {"child":[{"fruit":"apple","id":1},{"fruit":"mango","id":2,"child":[{"name":"js","id":4},{"name":"jsk","id":6}]},{"fruit":"banana","id":9}]}

function deleteById(data, ids) {
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    var i = data.length - 1;
    while (i > 0) {
      if (ids.includes(data[i].id)) data.splice(i, 1)
      deleteById(data[i], ids)
      i -= 1;
    }
  } else if (typeof data == 'object') {
    for (var i in data) {
      if (typeof data[i] == 'object') deleteById(data[i], ids)
    }
  }
}

deleteById(data, [6, 9])
console.log(data)
```