# Remove all keys with a same name from array of object

Tags: javascript

I have a array of Javascript objects, and I want to clear all the key-value pairs where the name of the key is `id`. How can I do this?

**Example input:**

```
var s = [{
  items:[{
    id: 1,
    items:[{
      items:[{
        id: 2,
        items:[]
      }]
    }]
  }],
  id: 3
}]
```

**Example output:**

```
var s = [{
  items:[{
    items:[{
      items:[{
        items:[]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively delete a list of values from object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719613/recursively-delete-a-list-of-values-from-object)

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of a recursive function like this:

```
function removeKey(obj, searchKey) {
  for(objKey in obj) {
    if (objKey === searchKey)
      delete obj[objKey];
    else if (typeof obj[objKey] === 'object')
      removeKey(obj[objKey], searchKey);
  }
}

removeKey(yourObj, 'id')
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/bsnfqkL9/3/

Answer (score 1):

You could beautify the iteration using a generator:

```
 function* flattenItems(items) {
  for(const item of items) {
    yield item;
    yield* flattenItems(item.items);
  }
}
```

So then your task is pretty simple:

```
 for(const item of flattenItems(s))
   delete item.id;
```